# providing the path to a library for ifort

Tags: fortran, intel-fortran

Disclaimer: This is not my field and I don't know the Jargon.

I'm trying to compile and run some code on a computation server. The machine have intel compiler installed on. When I try to compile the code using

```
ifort src.f -o mem
```

Everything works. If I try to optimize things:

```
ifort -fast src.f. -o mem
```

I first get messages:

```
ipo: remark #11001: performing single-file optimizations
ipo: remark #11006: generating object file /tmp/ipo_ifortYepD4m.o
```

Which seem logical. When I run the out file I get an error:

```
./mem: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I searched for `libgfortran`:

```
avityo@admin:~/prog/mn270.161> locate libgfortran
/home/MATLAB/R2011b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3
/home/MATLAB/R2011b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
/opt/matlab/r2012b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3
/opt/matlab/r2012b/sys/os/glnxa64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/libgfortran.a
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/libgfortran.so
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.3/libgfortranbegin.a
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3
/usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
```

Is there a way to tell ifort the available libgfort library?

Comment: This is really strange. Ifort should not depend on libgfortran and not on an old version of it. Are you sure you reproduced the compilation here EXACTLY? Why you have the other dot in `src.f.` there?

Comment: It is often instructive, when debugging run-time link problems, to use the `ldd` utility and peer at its output.

Comment: @VladimirF the extra dot is a type when I posted the question. The output is printed by the computation server when I try to run the output (bin?) file (this is a queue system) and not by the machine that compile the code.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark can you give me any link about how to do this?

Comment: Type `man ldd` at the command line.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Vladimir that it is a strange dependency between gfortran & ifort. However, it appears that ifort is looking for libgfortran.so.**1** and you have libgfortran.so.**3** listed there. You should be able link the former to the latter via `ln -s [target] [shortcut]`. That is,

```
    ln -s /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.3 /usr/lib64/libgfortran.so.1
```

Comment: How can I do this without root privilege?

Comment: By asking someone who does have root privilege: the cluster's IT Help Desk.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that.

Comment: You could make a symbolic link to your home directory (or wherever you have access to) and then add it to your LD_LIBRARY_PATH that should do the trick.

Comment: Why would you want to avoid asking the cluster's IT Help Desk? It is their _job_ to help you do stuff like this.

Comment: Because I'm lazy. This means to leave the office and explain the problem to him.